# Access: automatic date calculus

Tags: ms-access

In the Access table, I have 2 fields with `Date/Time` as `Data Type`: `[Start Date]` and `[End Date]`.

When I enter the `[Start Date]`, I would like that `[End Date]` takes automatically `[Start Date] + 3 years`. But at the same time, I should be able to modify the `[End Date]` after this automatic "suggest".

I have tried playing with `Default Value` without any success.

Comment: Try after update, on dirty, on change, on lost focus on the start date control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wazz suggests, requires code - VBA or macro - to save the calculated value and still allow user to edit field. The real trick is figuring out event(s) to use.

AfterUpdate might be best, VBA like:

```
Sub tbxStartDate_AfterUpdate()
Me.tbxEndDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 3, Me.tbxStartDate)
End Sub
```